# Spring Quartz JDBCJobStore issue

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I got stuck in using Spring Quartz Scheduling .

I am using JDBCJobStore to persist job status in Database , i got stuck while persist the same in DB while my job is running fine . 
My trigger entry in QRTZ_TRIGGERS table remains in WAITING state and after the job is executed there is another entry which goes to table - QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS and after completed the job it removes that entry from the database.

If anybody has ever worked on Spring Quartz API is highly appreciated .
So My question is pretty simple i.e. How i came to know whether my Quartz job has been successfully executed or not?

Comment: Are you asking whether Quartz stores information on every successful run? Like if it runs 10 times are you hoping to see 10 rows in some table capturing information about the run? Or you just want to be notified when a job has successfully competed execution? If its the former then you have to explicitly implement it. Quartz doesnt store historical data. If the latter take a look at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/listeners/JobListenerSupport.html Methods in there will be called once a job executes.

Comment: Thanks Srinivas , I think i have to explicitly implement it .